# Tmux Bind-key works when input through tmux command-line, but not from tmux.conf

Tags: configuration, tmux

Relatively new to tmux, and have been irritated the normal bash/zsh C-l to execute "clear" doesn't clear the screen. Decided to add a bind to tmux.conf to fix this, but I am running into this issue.

The line I am adding to tmux.conf is this -> `bind-key -n C-l send-keys "clear" \; send-keys "Enter"`

When I type this exact thing into the tmux command-line, the bind works as intended. However, when I source the tmux.conf or even kill server and restart, the bind does nothing. No errors thrown when sourcing the config or relaunching tmux, the rest of the (minuscule) config seems to work, but this bind just doesn't seem to work.

Maybe I am a tmux noob setting up tmux.conf incorrectly or maybe its a conflict with something else (terminal, shell, idek), but it is infuriating this simple thing can't just work. Can someone please help?

For context, I am running AlmaLinux9 in WSL2 and using the new Windows Terminal. Here is my tmux.conf for reference:

```
# Enable mouse mode (tmux 2.1 and above)
set -g mouse on

# Use ^l to clear terminal
bind-key -n C-l send-keys "clear" \; send-keys "Enter"

# --- Plugins --- #
# Fix TPM printing random characters on launch
set -s escape-time 1

# Set TPM install path
set-environment -g TMUX_PLUGIN_MANAGER_PATH '/home/brandon/.config/tmux/plugins/'

# List of plugins
set -g u/plugin 'tmux-plugins/tpm'
set -g u/plugin 'tmux-plugins/tmux-sensible'
set -g u/plugin 'christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator'

# Other examples:
# set -g u/plugin 'github_username/plugin_name'
# set -g u/plugin 'github_username/plugin_name#branch'
# set -g u/plugin 'git@github.com:user/plugin'
# set -g u/plugin 'git@bitbucket.com:user/plugin'

# Initialize TMUX plugin manager (keep this line at the very bottom of tmux.conf)
run '/home/brandon/.config/tmux/plugins/tpm/tpm'
```

What Have I Tried:
Tried binding the command through the tmux command-line, and that worked great. Tried adding to tmux.conf, but the bind seemingly does nothing. I did source the tmux.conf from inside tmux, still nothing. I did kill the tmux server, still the bind does nothing.

Comment: it worked for me. what version of tmux r u using?

Comment: @pynexj Version 3.2a

Comment: could you try disabling all the plugins?

Comment: @pynexj you beautiful genius. commented out plugin stuff from conf file and now it works as expected. Just tested and it appears to be something with 'christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator'. that actually makes sense, since that plugin uses C-l to switch split to the right. Likely I will figure out how to change that to use Alt instead of Control, because that really is a useful plugin.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be an issue with the default binds from the tmux plugin 'christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator'. Nothing wrong with tmux or the plugin, just a bind conflict. Actually makes sense because this plugin uses C-l to switch splits to the right. In retrospect, disabling plugins was clearly the right way to troubleshoot this issue. Guess I really am a noob. Thanks to @pynexy for the suggestion.